# log function errors on my part?

Tags: logarithms

Almost embarassed, but I cannot seem to get the same answer that is posted here...I keep getting .922, yet posted answer is .83.

can someone help me out here? I am told the answer to the equation below is 0.8310, yet every permutation I try to put into my TI-84 returns a value of .9227888

X = e^(((log315-log1200)/log150)*log2)

I am at my wits end and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the $\log$ in base $10$ or base $e$? The latter gives $0.831$, see [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28%28%28log315-log1200%29%2Flog150%29*log2%29&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C+%22log%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Log%22%7D). Click "use the base 10 logarithm instead" to get the other answer.

Comment: Your calculation used log to base 10, but you need log to the base e (probably "ln") on the calculator

Comment: I am new on this site, so it will not allow me to post screen grabs, but the original equation is this   315=1200*150^(logx/log2)

Comment: @jer Can you convert the math equation to MathJax? [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the guide, and https://www.desmos.com/calculator is a powerful software for copy-pasting formatted TeX

Comment: thank you both, I appreciate your response and I figured it out thanks to your insight, much appreciated

Comment: In the "original equation" the base of the $\log$ does not matter. If you use "log" on a calculator, its default base is $10$. So either you use the "ln" button on the calculator, or change to X = *10* ^(((log315-log1200)/log150)*log2) instead of using base $e$.